# incorrect data on history bars even recalculation on each bar

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Indicator gets incorrect data on historycal bars even recalculation on each bar:

```
//@version=5
indicator("test Bug 01")

signal_1_find (data) =>
    result = data[0] != 0  ? data[1]  : na 

prev_len = 5
start_len = 8
osc = 0.0
signal_1  = 0.0
signal_arr = array.new_float(6)
osc_arr = array.new_float(6)

for i = 0 to 5
    osc := 0.0
    length = start_len

    line_1 = ta.sma(close, length)
    line_2 = ta.sma(close, prev_len)

    osc := line_1 - line_2
    array.set(osc_arr, i, osc)
    array.set(signal_arr, i, signal_1_find (osc))
    
    start_len := length + prev_len  
    prev_len := length   


plot(osc, 'Oscillator', color.green, 2, plot.style_columns)

plot (array.get(signal_arr,0), display = display.status_line)
plot (array.get(signal_arr,1), display = display.status_line)
plot (array.get(signal_arr,2), display = display.status_line)
plot (array.get(signal_arr,3), display = display.status_line)
plot (array.get(signal_arr,4), display = display.status_line)
plot (array.get(signal_arr,5), display = display.status_line)

plot (array.get(osc_arr,0), display = display.status_line)
plot (array.get(osc_arr,1), display = display.status_line)
plot (array.get(osc_arr,2), display = display.status_line)
plot (array.get(osc_arr,3), display = display.status_line)
plot (array.get(osc_arr,4), display = display.status_line)
plot (array.get(osc_arr,5), display = display.status_line)
```

if I change this line

```
result = data[0] != 0  ? data[1]  : na
```

to

```
result = data[0] != 0  ? data[0]  : na
```

all data is correct because it takes data from [0] bar. If in this line data[x] where x - is any historical bar (except zero-bar) - signal_arr data becoming the same (equal) and in fact it equal the last loop iteration.

for example:

ocs =

```
bar 0: [1 2 3 4 5 6] 
bar 1: [11 12 13 14 15 16] 
bar 2: [21 22 23 24 25 26] 
etc
```

if `result = data[0] != 0  ? data[0]  : na`
result is correct:

result =

```
bar 0: [1 2 3 4 5 6] 
bar 1: [11 12 13 14 15 16] 
bar 2: [21 22 23 24 25 26]
```

if `result = data[0] != 0  ? data[1]  : na` result is INCORECT:

result =

```
bar 0: [16 16 16 16 16 16] 
bar 1: [26 26 26 26 26 26] 
bar 2: [36 36 36 36 36 36]
```

PineScript [manual tells](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Execution_model.html?highlight=execution%20pine%20functions%20historical%20context%20inside%20function%20block) about "historycal issues" but it take place when calculating is NOT every bar. In my case indicator it calculating on every bar.
Whats wrong and how I can get correct history data in this case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This expected behaviour of the series variables.

Lets's simplity your example:

1. Reduce the loop to 2 iterations
2. Calculate only 1 sma variable
3. Get rid of the function that returns the historical value of the variable (let's take the historical operator directly from the variable), because it does not affect the calculations and reflects same behaviour.

```
//@version=5
indicator("test Bug")

start_len = 8
osc = 0.0
signal_arr = array.new_float(6)
osc_arr = array.new_float(6)

for i = 0 to 1
    osc := 0.0
    length = start_len
    
    osc := ta.sma(close, length)
    
    array.set(osc_arr, i, osc)
    array.set(signal_arr, i, (osc[1]))
    
    start_len := length + 5   


plot (array.get(signal_arr,0), display = display.status_line)
plot (array.get(signal_arr,1), display = display.status_line)

plot (array.get(osc_arr,0), display = display.status_line, color = color.green)
plot (array.get(osc_arr,1), display = display.status_line, color = color.green)
```

Plot sma's values that were calculated in each iteration:

`i == 0`

```
//@version=5
indicator("sma(close,8), 1st iteration")
plot(ta.sma(close, 8))
```

`i == 1`

```
//@version=5
indicator("sma(close,13), 2nd iteration")
plot(ta.sma(close, 13))
```

Output. Variable `osc[0]`:

[image]

Output, variable `osc[1]`:

[image]

As you can see on 2nd screenshot accessing `osc[1]` returns values from the last iteration at the prescending bar.

Comment: Thanks for explanation! But it dont solve the problem to get history data if I recalc series several times on current bar ? 
Each loop iteration should recalc oscillator and I need to examine data on osc[1], osc[2], etc. In fact I see data on only one (last) loop iteration

Comment: you can put smas values inside array or a matrix and then you can access historical values of the array which will store values of sma on each iteration, each bar.
array.set(osc_arr, i, osc)  ... and then in the main scope call osc_arr[x], where x - bars ago